# Problem in specifying a path in a websocket server URL

Tags: python, websocket, path, endpoint, serve

I want to add a path to the end of the URL of websocket server, but it does not work.
For example `ws://111.111.11.111:8080/websocket`.
I want to add URL path `/websocket` after the port number like this. How do I do it?

1. First I tested, on the client side, `ws://111.111.11.111:8080/websocket`.
2. And secondly, changed URL to `ws://111.111.11.111:8080`.

The result was **both connected to the server**. And show the same output. Why? Can't it be connected only when the `/websocket` path is specified? What should I do?

###### Server side code

```py
import websockets

async def web_server(websocket, path):
    while True:
        publish_to_client = json.dumps(sub.status)
        await websocket.send(publish_to_client)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server = websockets.serve(web_server, "111.111.11.111", 8080)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

###### Client side code -> showing web

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://111.111.11.111:8080/websocket"),
                messages = document.createElement('ul');
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                    message = document.createElement('li'),
                    content = document.createTextNode(event.data);
                message.appendChild(content);
                messages.appendChild(message);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(messages);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python code has no mention of the path `"/websocket"` anywhere inside of it so I wouldn't expect it to do the filtering you desire.

> ```
> start_server = websockets.serve(web_server, "111.111.11.111", 8080)
> ```

The server is bound to an IP address and a port. Any incoming websocket connection will be dispatched to `web_server()`, no matter the path.

> ```
> async def web_server(websocket, path):
>     ...
> ```

This method handles all websockets. It's passed the `path` and it can use that information however it wishes. The method you wrote doesn't check the `path` variable so it will handle requests at any path as long as the IP address and port are correct.

If you want only certain paths to be accepted then you'll need to implement that logic yourself. Check `path` and accept or reject them with whatever logic you desire.

Comment: Thanks! I works! I added --->   if path == "/ws":    before sending data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what has been discussed here, the Server publishes everything with an IP and a port number.
The client needs to connect to the correct IP and port to retrieve the data.

If the server decides to send the data for clients with a specific address(as intended in here, e.g ws://192.168.56.1:7890/ws/myApp), then the server needs to set a condition to send the information out for clients that has connected with that address path.

So, in the **server** side,

```
....
async def WS_Server(websocket, path):


               if path == '/ws/myApp':
                    
                    await websocket.send(lineJSON)
                    
                
                else:
                    
                    print("Web Socket address path is wrong!")
                    print("\nClient must connect to ws://<yourIP>:<serverPort>/ws/driverapp.")
                    
         


....


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(WS_Server,"192.168.56.1",PORT):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```